# Angular NG3003 cycles with IVY compiler settings for Angular Lib when childComponent extends parentComponent

Tags: angular, ivy, cycle

i had to update a perfectly working lib in Angular from 11 to Angular 13.
I used the recommended settings for a lib

tsonfig File

```
"enableIvy": true,
    "compilationMode": "partial"
```

But i cannot compile the project, because of NNG3003 Error:

"ChildComponent" Error: One or more import cycles would need to be created to compile this component, which is not supported by the current compiler configuration.

Code of Child Component on its own is nothing special and the **only way** it reffers to parentComponent is like this

```
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {}
```

Important to say is that, that since this is a Lib, i do not refer to ParentComponent in HTML or any other way meaning i do not use something like  in the parent and wise versa.

Would love to hear how this could be solved as any other solutions with Injection Tokens and Interfaces i found on the Internet do not do the trick for me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with @Inject parent component into child component for using some parent methods. I solved it by moving those methods into separate service.